# How to call the minimum value in list 1 and respective value in list 2 in PYTHON

Tags: python, list

For example i have a two list as below

```
1 10
2 20
3 5
4 8
5 30
6 25
```

How to call the minimum value in list2 which is **5** as we can see and respective list1 value which is **3** as we can simply see.
but how to do it with python code

Comment: These are not python lists

Comment: Have you got these in a Python format?

Comment: assuming you really have 2 lists and not what you've written: `print(min(list2), list1[list2.index(min(list2))])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with min and zip quite easy:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
l2 = [10,20,5,8,30,25]

l3 = zip(l2,l1)

print(min(l3))
```

## Output:

```
(5, 3)
```

## Comment

As mention in the comment by [@sshashank124](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59857461/how-to-call-the-minimum-value-in-list-1-and-respective-value-in-list-2-in-python/59857560?noredirect=1#comment105847021_59857560) it is important that the first list is the list you want to find the minimum. In this case it would be `l2` that is why in `zip(l2,l1)` `l2` is first and not `l1`. Otherwise it wouldn't work and give you not the expected output.

As an example: `min(zip(l1,l2))` would return `(1, 10)`.

## Edit

You get a tuple back. Depending on which of this 2 elements you want you can print it like this:

```
min_value = min(l3)

print(min_value[0],min_value[1])
```

## Output:

```
5 3
```

Comment: It's important to note that the order of `zip`'s arguments matters since it performs a lexicographical sort on the tuple elements

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Now i can the get minimum value and respective another list value. now i can print (8, 5). but if i want to print only 5 then how to alter the code

Comment: @GovindKumar see update

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
>>> a = '''1 10
... 2 20
... 3 5
... 4 8
... 5 30
... 6 25'''
>>> data = [map( int, i.split()) for i in a.split('\n')]
>>> data
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 5], [4, 8], [5, 30], [6, 25]]
>>> inverted = [ [b,a] for a,b in data]
>>> inverted
[[10, 1], [20, 2], [5, 3], [8, 4], [30, 5], [25, 6]]
>>> sorted(inverted)
[[5, 3], [8, 4], [10, 1], [20, 2], [25, 6], [30, 5]]
>>> sorted(inverted)[0]
[5, 3]
>>>
```

Basically, you convert your data into the list of the integers, swap the items and sort the list.

The first element in the sorted list would be the lowest on the second list.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Boendal's answer, to be more sure you could use:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [10, 20, 5, 8, 30, 25]
l3 = zip(l2, l1)
print(min(l3, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Now i can the get minimum value and respective another list value. now i can print (8, 5). but if i want to print only 5 then how to alter the code. which means i can use the minimum value(list2) to call the respective value in list1 and finally wants to print only list1 value. how to alter the code

Comment: I go tit. Thanks for your time

Comment: @GovindKumar Since you have 15 reputation, may you please upvote all the answers?